# Notepad++ - Move insertion point to next line

Tags: notepad++

I am quite new to Notepad++ and I am doing some HTML and CSS coding in it.

My problem is that I would like a way to move the cursor to the next line, no matter if it is in the middle of some code in the previous line.

In PyCharm it is done by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and it's called "Start new line". I find it very useful, but haven't been able to find a similar way to do it in Notepad++.

I am running latest Windows 8 and Notepad++ (Je suis Charlie edition).

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Enter (or see Edit > Line Operations) is "Insert Blank Line Below Current" and moves the cursor to the start of that new line - is that what you want?

Comment: yeah its like that, the only difference is it doesn't start at the same indentation level as the previous line, but didnt mention that in my question either. 
Thanks, maybe I can work with recording a macro to make it start at the same indentation level as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Press "Record Macro" button.
2. Press "down arrow" button, next "home" button.
3. Press "Stop Recording".
4. Press "Save Current Macro"
5. Name is as you like "Start New Line"
6. Assign a shortcut (for me shift+enter didn't work, probably this shortcut is already in use)

Comment: Thanks!! Didn't even think of that! Now if I could find a way to make it go to the same indentation level as the previous line, i.e. the line before hitting down arrow it would be awesome.